# AWS EC2 instance - server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, certbot

I'm trying to setup Nextcloud on a AWS EC2 instance, and it all seems to work fine, except for 1 thing.

I've renamed the server from the original name to the proper domain:

```
ubuntu@nextcloud:/var/log/apache2# cat /etc/hostname
nextcloud.xxx-aws.com
```

The config in nextcloud-le-ssl.conf does reflect the correct domain name

```
ubuntu@nextcloud:/var/log/apache2# cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/nextcloud-le-ssl.conf
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/nextcloud/
  ServerName  nextcloud.xxx-aws.com
  ServerAlias nextcloud.xxx-aws.link

  <Directory /var/www/nextcloud/>
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews

    <IfModule mod_dav.c>
      Dav off
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains"
    </IfModule>

  </Directory>

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/nextcloud.xxx-aws.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/nextcloud.xxx-aws.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

But when I start apache, I have this message in the error log, and think this might make the application crash every now and then.

```
ubuntu@nextcloud:/var/log/apache2# tail -f error.log
[Wed Jan 24 06:40:42.392510 2024] [ssl:warn] [pid 459] AH01909: ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
```

The certificates are generated with Certbot.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

I'm not fully sure how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the hostname to localhost in /etc/hosts and renew the certificates seemed to have resolved the issue.